# Does $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

For$$\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$$

1. Does $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$ exist? If the answer is no, why?
2. Does $\bar{z}$ represents $a-bi$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\overline{x}^{2}}{z^{2}}$, or should the $x$ be a $z$? And yes, $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z=a+bi$, $\overline{z}=a-bi$.

Comment: @Peter I have changed $\bar{x}$ to $\bar{z}$ in the title.

Comment: If you don't know the answer to 2., you shouldn't be asking 1. !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $z = a + bi$, then $\bar{z} = a - bi$. Equivalently, if $z = r e^{i\theta}$, $\bar{z} = r e^{-i \theta}$.

Take $z = re^{i\theta}$ and as $z \to 0$, we have $r \to 0$.

Plug in $z = r^{i\theta}$ in $\dfrac{\bar{z}^2}{z^2}$. Now, let $r \to 0$ and see what happens for different $\theta$'s.